# Jquery sticky div is jittery in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I have 3 DIV elements on my page which I need to "sticky" at the top of the page when scrolling vertically. The elements are working ok in all browsers except for IE family; you can noticeably see the sticky animation and it's very jittery.

I have the following javascript to make my div sticky elements:

```
var name = "#webcto_menu";
var name2 = "#webcto_pane";
var name3 = "#webcto_pane_menu";
$(document).ready(function() {
    menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0,$(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        offset = menuYloc+$(document).scrollTop()+"px";
        $(name).animate({top:offset},{duration:0,queue:false});
    });
    menuYloc2 = parseInt($(name2).css("top").substring(0,$(name2).css("top").indexOf("px")))
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        offset = menuYloc2+$(document).scrollTop()+"px";
        $(name2).animate({top:offset},{duration:0,queue:false});
    });
    menuYloc3 = parseInt($(name3).css("top").substring(0,$(name3).css("top").indexOf("px")))
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        offset = menuYloc3+$(document).scrollTop()+"px";
        $(name3).animate({top:offset},{duration:0,queue:false});
    });
});
```

As you can see, each sticky is animating at 0ms (duration:0). Is it possible to use this method to behave more like a "css:fixed" element without animating the scroll-back? I did initially make my elements fixed, but had issues when browser window was too narrow (there was no horizontal scrolling with a fixed element.)

Comment: Can you please post a link to the page if possible and specify which versions of IE have the faulty behavior? I would also suggest a solution where you keep them fixed but when the browser is shrunk you put an element on the page that is not positioned fixed and spans the full width of the stickies so that you have horizontal scrolling. It's more dodgy but might work quite fine if you can implement it in a manner where you would be happy with it.

Comment: It would be better to just use css:fixed and correct it if the browser window is too narrow.

Comment: I never thought to do it that way, and I probably will implement that. Thanks for the suggestions!